# Restore application to show up on the main display

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

I have multiple monitors connected to Mac OS X.  After moving Firefox to a monitor other than the main display, I can't seem to get the Firefox back to start up on the main display.

I have tried:

1. Moving the Firefox window back to the main display, then shutdown Firefox.
2. Moving the Firefox window back to the main display, open a new Firefox window (it shows up on the same monitor) and moving it to main display, close individual window while it is still on the main display.

But Firefox still starts on the same display other than the main.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for mavericks is now to show an application's main window in whichever monitor it was started from. So if you're using the dock on a secondary monitor to open Firefox, it'll open in the secondary monitor's desktop.

If you create an additional desktop from mission control, you can right click apps in the dock and assign them to different desktops. So you could create a second desktop for your second monitor and assign Firefox to your main desktop to try and keep it sticky on your main monitor.

Comment: Firefox was started out from the main display.